# How to move the angularfire log in object to a service file

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I want to be able to use the logged in object globally on my site. I was wondering , how I can move the object to a service and utilize it to check for loggedin. Here is my log in controller:

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $location, userAuth) {
     $scope.login = function() {
      $scope.authData = null;
      $scope.error = null;

      userAuth.$signInWithEmailAndPassword($scope.loginemail, $scope.loginpassword)
      .then(function(authData) {
        $scope.authData = authData;
        console.log(authData);
      }).catch(function(error) {
        $scope.error = error.message;
      });
    };
```

And my service is:

```
.service('userAuth', ["$firebaseAuth", function($firebaseAuth) {
    return $firebaseAuth();
  }
```

I am able to log in successfully but I want to be able to use the logged in credentials globally. By so doing, how I should also prevent certain routes unless user is authenticated.

If a route is only for loggedin users, redirect them to the loggedin page. 
If they are already loggedin and they try to visit the signup page, logged them out.
And if they are loggedin and they try to visit the login page, redirect them to profile page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to store user data in service itself instead of returning it to caller. For example:

```
.service('userAuth', ["$firebaseAuth", function($firebaseAuth) {
    var userData;
    this.login = function(loginEmail, loginPassword){
       return $firebaseAuth
       .$signInWithEmailAndPassword(loginEmail, loginPassword)
       .then(function(authData) {
           userData = authData;
       });
    }
    this.getUserData = function(){
       return userData;
    }
  }
```

And use it in controller:

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $location, userAuth) {
     $scope.login = function() {
      $scope.authData = null;
      $scope.error = null;

      userAuth.login($scope.loginemail, $scope.loginpassword)
      .then(function() {
        $scope.authData = userAuth.getUserData();
        console.log($scope.authData);
      }).catch(function(error) {
        $scope.error = error.message;
      });
    };
```

Using this approach you gain couple of benefits:

1. Encapsulates login logic. This way you can easily change login
   service without disrupting any other parts of application.
2. You can get access to user data in any part of your application by injecting auth service and calling getUserData function.

To prevent user from accessing to particular routes you can use `$routeChangeStart` event to capture route change to stop navigation and then redirect to some other route depending on your business logic.

Comment: Thanks for the cool idea. How do I call this in the login controller?

Comment: Updated my answer. You can actually return user data from login function instead of calling getUserData afterwards but i think it is just matter of taste.

Comment: I am getting this then error  `angular.js:13920 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.login (login.js:17)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:14817), <anonymous>:4:206)`

Comment: Yeah, forgot to return promise from login function. Fixed the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I still can't get the redirect route to work. I will prefer a 'resolve' that checks if path is protected , redirect if not signed in.

Comment: Yes, that is another way to do that but you will need to add this logic to every resolve of every route.

Comment: I tried this but it won't work as I want. Do you have any example code for $routeChangeStart. I am new to angular and it's still being a cliff to climb.